# When I launch Metatrader 5 it closes after few seconds

Tags: wine, launcher, openstack

I try to open Metatrader 5, and it closes after few seconds. My system is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, 64bits. I don't know what happened. How do I fix it?

Comment: Yes, it works on Wine, till this afternoon perfectly. I've done some actualization today, informed by the system, so maybe sth has gone wrong. This is the only thing that comes to my mind from the history of actions that could had impact on this programs' behaviour.

Comment: I'm not very skilled in IT so I can't give more information about the actualization. Every week the system check it and send me a notification with recommended actualizations and I just do them. Maybe there a commend I can check the last actualizations made and paste it here? So you will have a clear information.

Comment: @Nmath "Actualizations" seems to be a bad translation of "upgrade".

Comment: Yes, karel is right, I mean upgrade. I hope this is exact term I can provide. So I just allow the recommended updgrades, without analizing nor remembering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution.
You need to uninstall/reinstall mt5.

To uninstall:

- Open a terminal
- Execute this command : `wine ~/.mt5/drive_c/'Program Files'/'MetaTrader 5'/uninstall.exe`
- Don't check the `Delete user personal data` if you don't want to delete all your mt5 settings
- Press next

To reinstall:
Follow the official mt5 installation on ubuntu https://www.metatrader5.com/en/terminal/help/start_advanced/install_linux

Comment: I had thought that maybe this is a solution but I was wondering about not loosing my data. And it works, it opens now normally and you have the date like the choosen indicators or drawings you made on the markets' graphs?

Comment: Like I said, you need to uncheck the box `Delete user personal data` if you don't want to lose your data.
Personnaly I don't lose anything, all the settings are the same!
But I don't use drawing directly on mt5, i'm using trading view.
I'm using an expert supervisor and the settings are the same as before I uninstall.

Comment: Thank you. I removed mt5 and installed again but before I change wine to the previous version (6).

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is occurring because of the last update.

I tried to install an older version and it worked. Here is a link to  from 2017 that contains instructions to downgrade the version.

here is an older version of mt5 :
c.mql5.com/3/151/terminal64.zip

Comment: in that link there are  3 different links to download older version of mt5 , just u had to look for it anyway i put it here https://c.mql5.com/3/151/terminal64.zip